# Deduce riemannian mapping theorem for domains of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ from uniformization theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I want to use the uniformization theorem, which states that every simply connected riemann surface is biholomorphically equivalent to either the riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ or the open disc $D = \{ x \in \mathbb{C} : |x| < 1 \}$,
to deduce that following corollary:

**Corollary:** Every simply connected domain $G \subseteq \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ which is missing at least two points from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is biholomorphically equivalent to $D$.

It's clear to me that due to compactness $G$ cannot be biholomorphically equivalent to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. But how do I show it's not biholomorphically equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$? When $x_0 \neq x_1$ are points of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ not in $G$, we know that $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \{x_0\}$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. So $G$ can be identified with a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Now how do I show that this subset cannot be biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ without prooving the standard riemann mapping theorem on its own? (or do I have to maybe?)

Comment: You need considerably less than the Riemann mapping theorem. After applying a Möbius transformation, you can assume that $G$ is a simply connected domain contained in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Now say "square root" or "logarithm" or some such.

Comment: expanding the comment/hint of Daniel, if you are able to take square root, then it's image will lie in a half plane, together with a Mobius transform, the image lies in the unit disk, then Liouville theorem tells you that $G$ cannot be $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and $G\subset\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\}$ be simply connected.
If we have a non-constant holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow G$, then $G=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{x\}$ by [Picard's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem). Thus $f$ cannot be biholomorphic.

Comment: Probably the OP will then have to ask how to prove Picard's little theorem using uniformization theorem....