# Basic question about Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

currently I am struggeling with the following issue that indicates my lack of knowlegde about simply connected Riemann surfaces, it goes as follows: Suppose that $\gamma \colon [0,t] \to \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is some simple curve in the complex plane that is bounded, i.e. infinity is not part of this simple curve.

By other questions on this website I know that $X \subseteq \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is simply connected iff both $X$ and its complement are connected, which is the case for $\gamma([0,t]) \subset \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$.

**Question**: Does there exist a conformal map $f \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\} - \gamma([0,t])$ that is onto?

**My thoughts**: Since $\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma([0,t])$ is simply connected, I want to apply the uniformization theorem for simply connected Riemann surfaces. But I am unsure if $\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma([0,t])$ is a Riemann surface and that the conformal equivalence is given by $\mathbb D$.

**My try**: It still should be a Riemann surface, since one can take the charts as an atlas

1. $U_1 = \mathbb C^{\ast} \setminus \gamma([0,t])$ with $\phi_1(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ and
2. $U_2 = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\} \setminus \gamma([0,t])$ with $\phi_2(z) = z$.

Now suppose the above is true then applying the uniformization theorem we know that $\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \gamma([0,t])$ is conformally equivalent to either the unit disk, the Riemann sphere or the complex plane. We rule out the latter two by observing that

1. I guess the Riemann sphere can be ruled out by invariance of domain, i.e. the punctured Riemann sphere and the Riemann sphere cannot be homeomorphic to each other.
2. I guess since the curve cuts out more than two points we can apply an argument directly given by [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485635/deduce-riemannian-mapping-theorem-for-domains-of-hat-mathbbc-from-uniform)

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a conformal map? (There are two inequivalent definitions.) And what do you mean by $\hat{\mathbb C}$?

Comment: I denote by $\hat{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ and suppose that $G \subseteq \hat{\mathbb C}$ is a domain, I call a function $f : G \to H$ conformally onto if $f$ is meromorphic in $G$/injective/$f(G)=H$, i.e. it is not definiton of just non-vanishing derivative.